# Find the irreducible decomposition of $x^{16}+x$ over $\mathbb{F_8}=\mathbb{F_2}[t]/(t^{3}+t+1)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

> Question: Find the irreducible decomposition of $$x^{16}+x$$ over $\mathbb{F_8}=\mathbb{F_2}[t]/(t^{3}+t+1)$.

It's easy to show that $$x^{16}+x=x(x+1)(x^{2}+x+1)(x^{4}+x+1)(x^{4}+x^{3}+1)(x^{4}+x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1)$$in $\mathbb{F_2}[x]$, but how to get the irreducible decomposition of $$(x^{4}+x^{3}+1)(x^{4}+x+1)(x^{4}+x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1)$$
over $\mathbb{F_8}$? Thanks a lot.

Comment: A general rule about irreducible polynomials over a finite field $K$ is that if $p(x)\in K[x]$ is a degree $m$ irreducible polynomial, and $[F:K]=n$, then $p(x)$ remains irreducible over $F$ if and only if $\gcd(m,n)=1$. I think we have covered this on the site already. It follows rather quickly from the uniqueness of an extension of a given degree.

Comment: Or simply [by an application of the tower law](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/987787/11619).

Comment: [A relevant special case](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2324141/11619).

Comment: [This.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1973330/11619)

Answer (score 3):

Each over $\mathbb F_2$ irreducible polynomial of degree $4$ is irreducible over $\mathbb F_8$ as well. The reason is quite easy: A polynomial of degree $4$ would factor over $\mathbb F_{2^4}=\mathbb F_{16}$ into linear factors. Since $\mathbb F_{16} \cap\mathbb F_{8}=\mathbb F_{2}$ no factorisation of such a polynomial is visible in $\mathbb F_8$.